# Create policy group

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is it possible to create a policy group from the AOT in Dynamics AX 2012?

If not, what is the recommended way to create policy groups and what permissions are required to create those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security policies are created in AOT\Security\Policies. You need developer rights to do so.

Security policy groups are created by typing the name (free text) in the property window of the security policy. The new name will appear in the lookup next time you do a lookup in the property.

Comment: This is creating a security policy. My question is how to create a Security Policy Group for policies.

Comment: Where do you see such things?

Comment: In a Security Policy's property there is a PolicyGroup property listed in there. That's what I need to create